# Why does Laravel authentication require the 'web' guard?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I have setup Laravel 5.5 and installed the default authentication scaffolding.

My application has two types of users - customers and staff - so I prefer to name the authentication guards that way, and the following configuration seems to work.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customer-users',
    ],
    'staff' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'staff-users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
```

My providers, customer-users and staff-users, use the standard eloquent driver, however they each return a different user type.

The problem is that I would like to remove the 'web' guard, since it's just cluttering the config file.  When I do however, I get an exception somewhere deep in the Laravel middleware.

I can live with the extra clutter of course, but it does bother me that Laravel is relying on a configuration item that I can't change.  Is this a Laravel bug, perhaps?

BTW - I don't have 'web' set as the default guard when I get the error...

Comment: i was wondering the same thing, i just overwrote the routes to the default auth to some other login page that i defined as default

Answer (score 1):

By default **web** guard given by laravel which used for web authentication based on `session` driver with the table `users`. Now you have created your own custom guards and you are using it. So your wish to keep that `web guard`. But if you remove, you might be facing some internal issue, so best you keep it and it's not going to be the performance issue too.